# I can't understand this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, sentence-meaning, concept

I read an English text. In this text I came across a sentence that I can't understand it as a complete sentence:
"In this context and who can argue against the ethos of closer observation of what industry is up to."

I think the sentence is incomplete‌ and the whole sentence is the subject!
can anyone help me?

Is it possible that the concept is related to the previous sentence?
"Such PR events will continue to grow as industry–university liaison gathers apace."

Comment: It seems to make slightly more sense if you take the *and* out, perhaps replacing it with a comma. By the way, you should say where you quoted your phrases from: [*The Dark Side of Marketing Communications: Critical Marketing Perspectives*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WJ_5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53) by Tim Hill, Pierre McDonagh (Routledge 2021), p53.

Comment: thanks Mr. Leach. you are right. I forgot to mention the reference.

Comment: That comment doesn't preclude someone actually giving an answer. Even with that rather major adjustment, it's still not very good. "liaison gathers apace"? Really?

Answer (score 1):

It means,

**In this context, it would surely meet with general approval if the actions of industry were routinely scrutinized.**

Or

**Speaking of which, we should routinely scrutinize the actions of industry.**

It's very poor English. The word "and" doesn't belong in it. The sentence should end with a question mark. The overused expression "*the ethos of...*" is best followed with something short and pithy that *sounds* like an ethos: an ethos of  "community cohesion" for example, or of "self-belief".

"Gathers apace" should probably be be "**gathers pace**".